# Connecting my iOS app to a Web Application using JSON and POST problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, swift, postgresql, http

I am new to back end app creation so all of this is quite confusing at the moment. I am currently trying to allow an iOS app I have created to save details into a Rails web application's PostgreSQL database. The web application and database work well. I am trying to use JSON and POST requests to communicate with the web application which is shown in this function:

```
    func connect(){  
    let baseUrl = URL(string: "URL_HERE")
    var request = URLRequest(url: baseUrl!)
    let session = URLSession.shared

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let stringPost = "name=test&surname=man"

    let data = stringPost.data(using: .utf8)!

    request.timeoutInterval = 60
    request.httpBody=data

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, URLResponse, Error -> Void in

        let err1: NSError? = nil

        do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
        }
        catch{
            print(err1!)
            print("Error")
        }

    })
    task.resume()

}
```

All i want is for a user to be saved to the database.
Each time this method is executed it throws an error.
This is the only method I have. I'm sure that I'm missing part of the procedure but I'm having a hard time finding what it is. I'm not even sure how to find out more about why the error has been thrown.

Any help at all on this would be much appreciated I'm at quite a loss.

Comment: It prints out error nil and Error when the function is called

Comment: @B-Brenan What's the error you're receiving? You're not setting err1 anywhere.

Comment: I am getting nil printed out and the Error printed out, I'm presuming it's because the try is failing?

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting anyhow?

When communicating with your web services API, you might want to look into [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) which is easy to use, does most the heavy lifting for you, and has a pretty grounded support community.

Here are some examples using Alamofire, you'll have to fill in some blanks, but it's a start.

**This is the method I used to authenticate a user using Alamofire using Swift 3**

```
 func authenticateAsync(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ token: String?, _ status: String?, _ error: String?, _ response: DataResponse<Any>) -> Void) {
          let accumooParameters = self.formatAuthenticationParameters(email: email, password: password)
          let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.mysite.api-response-queue",
                                            qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated,
                                            attributes: DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent)

          Alamofire.request(Globals.Accumoo.Urls.Authentication.authenticateUser,
                            method: HTTPMethod.post,
                            parameters: accumooParameters,
                            encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                            headers: ["Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"])
             .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
             .responseJSON(queue: dispatchQueue, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments, completionHandler: {
                (response: DataResponse<Any>) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                   let json:JSON = JSON(data)
                   print(json.rawString()!)
                   let result = self.getAuthenticationResult(json: json)
                   completion(result.token, result.status, result.error, response)
                case .failure(let error):
                   completion("", String(describing: response.response?.statusCode ?? 0), String(error._code), response)
                }
             })
       }

internal func formatAuthenticationParameters(email: String, password: String) -> [String : Any]? {
      return ["email" : email, "password" : password]
   }

   internal func getAuthenticationResult(json: JSON) -> (token: String?, status: String?, error: String?) {
      let token = json["token"].string
      let status = json["status"].string
      let error = json["error"].string
      return getAuthenticationResult(token: token, status: status, error: error)
   }

   internal func getAuthenticationResult(token: String?, status: String?, error: String?) -> (token: String?, status: String?, error: String?) {
      return (token: token, status: status, error: error)
   }
```

**This is the method I used to post an authenticated request using Alamofire using Swift 3 in the same app**

```
     // Update full name
   func updateFullName(with accessToken: String, fullName: String, completion: @escaping (DataResponse<Any>) -> Void) {
      let url = "https://api-mysite.herokuapp.com/mysite/users/update_user/"

      let params =  ["user" : ["full_name" : fullName]]

      put(with: accessToken, url: url, params: params, completion: { (dataResponse: DataResponse<Any>) in
         completion(dataResponse)
      })
   }

    // Post authenticated
       internal func post(with accessToken: String, url: String, params: [String : Any], completion: @escaping (DataResponse<Any>) -> Void) {
          let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.mysite.api-response-queue",
                                            qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated,
                                            attributes: DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent)
          Alamofire.request(url,
                            method: HTTPMethod.post,
                            parameters: params,
                            encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                            headers: ["Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=UTF-8; version=1",
                            "Authorization" : accessToken])
             .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
             .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
             .responseJSON(
                queue: dispatchQueue,
                options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments,
                completionHandler: { (response: DataResponse<Any>) in completion(response) }
          )
       }
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a compulsory project I have so I'll need to solve  this problem in some way. The thing is, the rails web app is already fully functional and works with an existing android app I just need to make a iOS client that operates on the web app. I know that it's not an easy project but I just need some pointers in the right direction.

Comment: @B-Brennan, if that's the case, my answer still stands as far as using Alamofire. You also need to look into what authentication the Rails app is using and account for that as well, otherwise, all of your requests will fail. I'll post an example of how to call your web services using Alamofire, but there are also a lot of examples out there to do so.

Comment: Thanks that would be very much appreciated. Is there an easy way to check what authentication the rails app is using?

Comment: @B-Brennan it would have to be token-based I imagine, there aren't any other viable options really, ask the dude(s)/dudette(s) who maintain the rails app. Most likely you'll have to authenticate first, and get back the auth token. You'll then have to use that auth token in all your subsequent calls to the server to authenticate each request. The auth token is usually passed in the header of the request.

Comment: Okay I can find that out for sure. I understand the procedure you're explaining but is there anywhere you know online that I can learn more about the implementation of it?

Comment: @B-Brennan, yes, just follow the link in my post, get familiar with the API, and start checking around on stackoverflow. I'll post some of my code snippets, but they are only to get you started, you'll have to fill in the blanks.